# IMDbPy with WinPython

Tags: python, spyder, imdb, imdbpy

I'm trying to get a version of IMDbPy that I can install using the WinPython installer - there are a variety of programs that have been made compatible with, however IMDbPy doesn't have a specific WinPython package.

I've tried to download several different versions of it and install it with the WinPython Installer, however most of them have instantly been rejected due to the incorrect file type for the package; I got one to be accepted only for it to reject it later in the process.

I'm just wondering if there is a way to get the software installed and usable within Spyder.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion (may or may not work):

- launch "Winpython Command Prompt"
- type 'pip install IMDbPy'

....

- type 'pip list' to check pip did install it

Comment: This partially works. It finds the file, however it finds an invalid syntax within the IMDbPY file. I'll try redownloading the file. I know I downloaded multiople types of the file so perhaps it's looking at the 'wrong' file.

Comment: I tried to update pip, in case that was causing some sort of issue (hopeful, I know). I tried several downloads and they all have the same syntax error.

Comment: what version of WinPython do you use ? what is the syntax error message ?

Comment: I use WinPython 3.4.3.4 (64 bit). The syntax error seems to be in the setup.py file in the IMDbPy temporary pip folder, line 200 that prints 'Created locale for: %s.'%' '.join(languages). The arrow points to the apostrophe before the second %.